# Is it legal to let people search for professionals by gender?

Tags: california, texas, discrimination

Prompted by the list of injunction demands from a [recent lawsuit against Uber](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/10/uber-sued-over-two-alleged-driver-assaults/), I'm curious whether or not it's legal in California, Texas and elsewhere to discriminate on a profession such as a barber by sex.  What about a doctor?  A nurse?  A masseuse?  An Uber driver?  A real-estate agent?  A cook?  A general contractor?

If it's legal, we start up with personal discrimination — letting and abetting a *natural person* customer to specify and select a doctor/barber/driver/etc by gender.
But, then, wouldn't supply and demand laws dictate the necessity for *corporate* discrimination at a certain point?  Would that be legal?  Where is the line drawn?

Specifically, would it be legal to have listings where in search of a professional in a given occupation, the end customer could explicitly specify their search preference by gender?

Comment: For what it's worth, my health insurance company (one of the giants, who undoubtedly have a large legal department) does allow members to search for doctors by gender.

Comment: Why did this question generate so many views so shortly?  (At 1,1k now!)  Has it been posted externally somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

It is not legal for an *employer* to discriminate on the basis of sex anywhere in the US (see http://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/sex.cfm). Exemptions exist where the discrimination is for [bona fide occupational qualifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bona_fide_occupational_qualifications) and, irrelevantly, religious reasons.

It is completely legal for a *consumer* to discriminate on the basis of anything they want to. It is also legal for a business to assist the consumer in that discrimination.

Bona fide occupational qualifications generally only apply to instances in which the BFOQ is considered reasonably necessary to the normal operation of a particular business. Mere customer satisfaction, or lack thereof, is not enough to justify a BFOQ defence, as noted in the cases Diaz v. Pan Am. World Airways, Inc. and [Wilson v. Southwest Airlines Co.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Wilson_v._Southwest_Airlines_Co.). Therefore, customer preference for females does not make femininity a BFOQ for the occupation of flight attendant. However, there may be cases in which customer preference is a BFOQ—for example, femininity is reasonably necessary for Playboy Bunnies. Customer preference can "'be taken into account only when it is based on the company's inability to perform the primary function or service it offers,' that is, where sex or sex appeal is itself the dominant service provided."

None of the occupations you mention would, on the face of it, meet the requirements to be BFOQ.

Allowing their customers to express a *preference* for a specific gender may impact on the capacity for the business to deliver on that preference but it would not generally allow a BFOQ defence if this impacted their hiring policies. A possible exception is if the business catered to that preference *exclusively*, for example, an all female gym with all female staff *but* I am not aware that this has ever been tested and if a male personal trainer wanted to take them on he may very well win.

As an aside, there is no BFOQ defence for *racial* discrimination except for artistic works where the first amendment rights overrule the anti-discrimination laws.

Comment: I guess your first sentence is not really true in all cases, as there are exceptions. What about a fashion model for women's underwear? Or what about casting a role for Napoleon in a theatre or movie? There you are allowed to discriminate even based on race and facial features. What about hiring a new priest or other staff for a religious institution? I'm pretty sure that you can base the selection on religion in that case.

Comment: `Bona fide occupational qualifications generally only apply to instances in which the BFOQ is considered reasonably necessary to the normal operation of a particular business. Mere customer satisfaction, or lack thereof, is not enough to justify a BFOQ defence`  Hooters uses BFOQ to hire only female waitresses and to enforce stringent weight standards.  That seems to be entirely a matter of customer satisfaction.

Comment: Dale, are you sure aiding is allowed?  For example, I recall reading in Craigslist policies (and elsewhere) that it is allowed for a live-in landlord to discriminate potential tenants on whatever features they wish, but it is NOT allowed to state such features in the ad itself etc.  Why do you allege that the situation here is different?

Comment: @EricJ. Hooter's BFOQ defense has never went to trial. Every case has been settled. Many scholars doubt that it would succeed at trial, especially because it is merely due to customer preferences. Customer preference has been held in two cases (Pan Am, and Southwest Airlines) to not rise to the level of a BFOQ.

Comment: @nomenagentis, so, does it mean any male can just apply to be a waiter at hooters, and profit with a free settlement?

Comment: @cnst [read this](http://scholarship.law.duke.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1160&context=djglp) for the limits of the BFOQ defense and how customer preference doesn't generally matter, and how Hooters settled.

Comment: @cnst Craigslist policies may be (and are allowed to be) more stringent than the law.

Comment: @DaleM, no, it's specifically due to law; I recall other roommate matching web-sites also had legal problems seeking and distributing that kind of data; see https://www.craigslist.org/about/FHA#roommates

Comment: @cnst: you link to something that cites the Federal Fair Housing laws (I assume the Fair Housing Act, Title VIII of the Civil Rights Act of 1968), which regulate housing ads. So, there may be other differences, but it seems likely straight away that this case is different because Fair Housing laws have nothing to say about the selection of or advertising to barbers, doctors, etc. They relate to the selection of and advertising to tenants.

Comment: Thank you for sharing link to - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bona_fide_occupational_qualifications - I was always wondering if it legal to ```discriminate```, say, a wheelchair user and refuse them high-altitude alpinist work.

Comment: Regarding potential, live-in tenants and Craigslist: if by live-in tenants you mean roommates, it is perfectly legal to discriminate and to state preferences in advertising according to a ninth circuit ruling in Fair Housing Council of San Fernando Valley v. Roommates.com. Craigslist can have more restrictive policies if they wish. It is illegal discrimination to advertise for tenants who are not roommates, i.e. not sharing living quarters, by specifying anything that's part of a protected class.

Comment: @nomenagentis The difference between Hooters and the airlines is that Hooters is specifically selling service by women fitting a certain image.  The airlines were selling transportation, and using the physical image of their crew as a means of attracting business.  With Hooters, the waitresses are a major part of the product.

Comment: @DaveD craigslist basically follows the law: "However, as discussed below, advertising which expresses a preference based upon sex is allowed in shared living situations where tenants will share a bathroom, kitchen, or other common area."

Comment: @cnst craigslist explicitly allows roommate ads to target a specific sex if there are shared common areas.  See my previous comment.

Comment: @phoog that argument was attempted by the airlines. It was not successful. See the review article by Manley. Read the Pan Am and Southwest opinions. The *manner* in which a company decides to deliver its product isn't part of the product for BFOQ purposes.

Comment: @phoog From *Southwest*: "*That Southwest's female personnel may perform their mechanical duties "with love" does not change the result. "Love" is the manner of job performance, not the job performed.*" Most believe that courts would see the physical appearance of the Hooters waitresses as a component of the "manner" of the job performance, and not the job performed.

Comment: @phoog Even if the sexual female image has become part of the trademark identity of Hooters, *Southwest* said: "*Merely because Southwest's female image was established in good faith and has become its trademark does not distinguish Defendant's conduct from the discriminatory business decisions disapproved of in these cases.*"

Comment: @nomenagentis I think Hooters is rather more similar to a strip club than to an airline.  That is, the sexy woman is an integral part of its product, which is marketed to men.  There is a huge segment of the restaurant industry that does not take this approach.  Airlines sell travel with the entire population as their market.

Comment: @phoog Well, most people that have published opinions about this in peer reviewed law journals disagree that that argument would be successful. If you could just deem the "manner" that you choose to provide your service as the service itself, that would be an end-around the law.